# How to write decoded data matrix to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datamatrix

I'm trying to read all data matrixes from an image and write to dataframe.
I can print barcode number and location via pylibdmtx but I can't figure out how to store in dataframe

```
image = cv2.imread('IMG-4951.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
plt.imshow(gray)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
msg = pylibdmtx.decode(thresh)
print(msg)


Output:
[Decoded(data=b'01086995460155972150046789702417240229109LB02199', rect=Rect(left=984, top=1172, width=290, height=287)), Decoded(data=b'01086995460155972154702360250417240229109LB02199', rect=Rect(left=899, top=2242, width=279, height=272))]
```

'msg' variable stored as list with 2 elements in this case and when I try to convert pandas Dataframe 'data' column is blank but 'rect' column is proper like above. `(Rect(left=984, top=1172, width=290, height=287))`

Dataframe looks like below;

```
data      rect
          Rect(left=984, top=1172, width=290, height=287)
          Rect(left=899, top=2242, width=279, height=272)
```

How can I fill data column or any other method do you suggest?

My second question is, this library seems very slow any suggestion how to make it quicker?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: hey! i was trying to run this code. This is a fascinating package! can i ask, how did you get issues with [Unable to find dmtx shared library] when trying to import from pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx import decode. I tried this as the output was failing when trying to store a variable.

Comment: Hi! I figured out my issues with **[Unable to find dmtx shared library]** and provided an answer which _might_ be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be helpful

I used this test image

[image]

Import the packages

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx import decode
import pandas as pd
```

Use the code you provided above

```
image = cv2.imread('datamatrix.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
plt.imshow(gray)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
msg = decode(thresh)
print(msg)
```

I get this output,

```
[Decoded(data=b'Stegosaurus', rect=Rect(left=5, top=6, width=96, height=95)), Decoded(data=b'Plesiosaurus', rect=Rect(left=298, top=6, width=95, height=95))]
```

[image]

To add to a dataframe I start with populating a list to represent the shape I would like the dataframe to be

```
ls_msg = []
for item in msg:
    ls_msg.append([item[0], item[1][0], item[1][1], item[1][2]])
```

Make list into a dataframe

```
df_msg = pd.DataFrame(ls_msg)
```

Add column names

```
df_msg.columns = ['data', 'left','top','width']
```

This produces a dataframe which looks like this

[image]

Never used this package before it was fascinating to install and play!

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I want to ask that does 'decode' process is long in your system? Just checking if I do sth wrong or missing, because it takes approximately 2 minutes which is very long comparing the barcode process results

Comment: Hey @Tyr , for that particular image it ran quickly, under 5 seconds